# Oracle: Dynamically create package scripts without writing to a file

Tags: oracle, file, package, execute

I have built my own repository of tables in my oracle database.

I use this repository to create standardazied packages per table.
Up to now I write a bunch of scripts into a utitlity folder.

I don't want to go that extra way though the file system anymore.

This is an example file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE vpk_0003_produkte
AS

   TYPE t_cursor IS REF CURSOR;

   PROCEDURE p_insert (p_rc                  OUT NUMBER,
                       p_rc_text             OUT VARCHAR2,
                       p_logsql            IN     NUMBER,
                       p_logperformance   IN     NUMBER,
                       p_user_id            IN     NUMBER,
                       p_mandant          IN  NUMBER, 
                       -- PK Columns
  p_id IN OUT x_0003_produkte.id%TYPE
                       -- Other Columns
, p_requestid IN     x_0003_produkte.requestid%TYPE);

   PROCEDURE p_update (p_rc                  OUT NUMBER,
                       p_rc_text             OUT VARCHAR2,
                       p_logsql            IN     NUMBER,
                       p_logperformance   IN     NUMBER,
                       p_user_id            IN     NUMBER,
                       p_mandant          IN  NUMBER, 
                       p_where            IN     VARCHAR2,
                       -- PK Columns
  p_id IN OUT x_0003_produkte.id%TYPE
                       -- Other Columns
, p_requestid IN     x_0003_produkte.requestid%TYPE);

END vpk_0003_produkte;
```

Is there a way to execute these lines directly without writing a file? 
I know of "OPEN CURSOR FOR" in conjunction with a variable that contains a SELECT to get data. But how to execute/write?

ADDITIONAL INFO: One package code easily has 27.000 characters! and around 1000 lines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assemble the entire source of the package DDL into a single `VARCHAR2(32000)` local variable, you should be able to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to run the DDL

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_your_ddl_stmt;
```

Depending on the Oracle version, you may be able to call `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` with a `CLOB` if the DDL statement might exceed 32000 bytes.  You can also use `dbms_sql` passing in a collection of `VARCHAR2(4000)` strings that are combined into the DDL that you want to execute.

Assuming that you are checking your generated code into source control, though, rather than just checking in the code that generates the package, it may well be easier to generate the files on the file system as an intermediate step since that allows you to both commit to source control and to create the object in the database.